# Accessing multiple parameter values in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, url-parameters

From this [article](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/) from Martin Hawksey, summarized:

a script bound to the Sheet is published as a web app, a form uses jQuery's $.ajax to send the request to that web app, and the web app handles the parameters into columns of the Sheet with headers matching the *names* of each param. (the script in this article makes use of PublicLock, which I've changed to ScriptLock)

My problem revolves around checkboxes. Inside the request, I'll see

```
...fruit=apple&fruit=banana&fruit=cantaloupe...
```

and the Apps Script will see this as well, passing `e` to a function `handleResponse()` which is triggered from `doPost(e)`. To access the values for the parameters in the request, we use `e.parameter` or `e.parameters`. I've chosen the latter to accommodate for checkboxes and multiple values for that particular parameter.

What's not happening, though, is exactly that: only the first checkbox value is being sent through. To iterate through params, we use

```
for (i in headers) {
   if (headers[i] == "Timestamp") {
     row.push(new Date());
   } else {
      row.push( e.parameters[headers[i]] );
   }
}
```

to push the values for each parameter that matches a column header into a new array that will be entered as a new row. To do that, Hawksey uses

```
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row])
```

I guess I'm having trouble understanding what `e.parameters` does and how I can access the those values. I understand that the `parameters` property houses the values of each name as *arrays*, but I can't get an array's entire list of elements to be the value for a cell in a row. Can someone help me understand what `e.parameters` does, and how I can better get to all of the values I need?

Answer (score 4):

`e.parameters` is an object where the parameters are the object keys and the values are stored in an array. So, a request like this:

```
url?fruit=apple&fruit=orange&fruit=lime&animal=giraffe
```

would yield an object like this:

```
{'fruit': ['apple', 'orange', 'lime'], 'animal': ['giraffe']}
```

If you have to put all values for `fruit` into one cell, you might try:

```
e.parameters.fruit.join(',')
```

which will return a string with each value separated by a comma. Then, if you need to separate the values again, you could use `String.split()` (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)).

Comment: You could also mention that the (scant) documentation about the `doGet(e)` parameters is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service#doGetParams), as part of the docs for the deprecated UI Service. (They really should have that somewhere more prominent.)

Comment: Actually [Web Apps and Google Sites Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters) has a better piece.